# how to pass textbox value to @"somestring"

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

```
 string htmlPage = @"<div class=""wecome"" id=""about"">        
                      <h3>Welcome "+TexName.Text+"</h3> 
                    </div>";
```

I want to pass texbox value to textbox.text.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TexName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
```

I am using @ because htmlpage variable contains almost 400 lines of html code. Without @ it is giving syntax errors.

Comment: Do you have a asp textbox? or a normal one? please provide some more code.

Comment: @JoshuadV Pleas check the updated question

Comment: okay so you have a asp textbox, and you want to pass the value of the textbox to html right? do you set the textbox.text anywhere?

Comment: @JoshuadV Yes.  <h3>Welcome "+TexName.Text+"</h3>

Comment: have a look at shreesha's answer, maybe he's right and you have just a problem with the " "

Comment: The `@` works for just the string that directly follows. You will need to repeat that for every string (where needed). So you need `... TexName.Text + @"</h3>...`

Comment: @HansKesting  +1 for your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
   string htmlPage = @"<div class=" + "\"wecome\"" + " id=" + "\"about\"" + ">" +
                       "<h3>Welcome " + TexName.Text + "</h3>" +
                     "</div>";
```

Comment: @shreesha.  htmlPage variable contains 400 lines of html code. Do i need to put "", +  for  all those lines?

Comment: @shreesha  Thanks for your answer. With small modification of your answer my code is working fine.